# Performance gain on call chaining?

Tags: performance, erlang

Do you gain any performance, even if it's minor, by chaining function calls as shown below or is it just coding style preference?

```
execute() -> 
   step4(step3(step2(step1())).
```

Instead of

```
execute() ->
   S1 = step1(),
   S2 = step2(S1),
   S3 = step3(S2),
   step4(S3).
```

I was thinking whether in the 2nd version the garbage collector has some work to do for `S1`, `S2`, `S3`. Should that apply for the 1st version as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are identical after compilation. You can confirm this by running the erl file through `erlc -S` and reading the generated `.S` file:

```
$ cat a.erl
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

step1() -> ok.
step2(_) -> ok.
step3(_) -> ok.
step4(_) -> ok.

execute1() ->
   step4(step3(step2(step1()))).

execute2() ->
   S1 = step1(),
   S2 = step2(S1),
   S3 = step3(S2),
   step4(S3).
$ erlc -S a.erl
$ cat a.S
{module, a}.  %% version = 0

...

{function, execute1, 0, 10}.
  {label,9}.
    {line,[{location,"a.erl",9}]}.
    {func_info,{atom,a},{atom,execute1},0}.
  {label,10}.
    {allocate,0,0}.
    {line,[{location,"a.erl",10}]}.
    {call,0,{f,2}}.
    {line,[{location,"a.erl",10}]}.
    {call,1,{f,4}}.
    {line,[{location,"a.erl",10}]}.
    {call,1,{f,6}}.
    {call_last,1,{f,8},0}.


{function, execute2, 0, 12}.
  {label,11}.
    {line,[{location,"a.erl",12}]}.
    {func_info,{atom,a},{atom,execute2},0}.
  {label,12}.
    {allocate,0,0}.
    {line,[{location,"a.erl",13}]}.
    {call,0,{f,2}}.
    {line,[{location,"a.erl",14}]}.
    {call,1,{f,4}}.
    {line,[{location,"a.erl",15}]}.
    {call,1,{f,6}}.
    {call_last,1,{f,8},0}.

...
```

As you can see, both `execute1` and `execute2` result in identical code (the only thing different are line numbers and label numbers.

Comment: I could't find any reference of `-S` option in correlation to assembler code generation in the docs. It is stated the `.S` files contain assembler code, but it does not tell you how to generate them. http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlc.html